# Tune the unpivot script to another way for data extraction

Tags: oracle

I would like to convert the unpivot script because it take a long time to extract the data from Back-end. However, may I know the easy way extract data from back-end by using cross apply... or another way.

Sample Script :

```
SELECT 
    cm.cust_acct_no as "dd",
    ( 
    SELECT
        COALESCE(sum((select kca.active_account from kyc_count_account kca where kca.CUST_ACCT_NO = joint_acct)),0,0)
      FROM
        (SELECT
          (lpad('0', (16-length(t.link_cua_acno_01)), '0')||t.link_cua_acno_01) AS acct01
          ,(lpad('0', (16-length(t.link_cua_acno_02)), '0')||t.link_cua_acno_02) AS acct02
          ,(lpad('0', (16-length(t.link_cua_acno_03)), '0')||t.link_cua_acno_03) AS acct03
          ,(lpad('0', (16-length(t.link_cua_acno_04)), '0')||t.link_cua_acno_04) AS acct04
          ,(lpad('0', (16-length(t.link_cua_acno_05)), '0')||t.link_cua_acno_05) AS acct05
          ,(lpad('0', (16-length(t.link_cua_acno_06)), '0')||t.link_cua_acno_06) AS acct06
          ,(lpad('0', (16-length(t.link_cua_acno_07)), '0')||t.link_cua_acno_07) AS acct07
          ,(lpad('0', (16-length(t.link_cua_acno_08)), '0')||t.link_cua_acno_08) AS acct08
        FROM cbsdbap1.cusvcc t
        WHERE substr(t.key_1,4,16) = cm.cust_acct_no and t.code = 'CC' and rownum <= 1
    ) temp unpivot include NULLS (joint_acct FOR kind IN (acct01, acct02, acct03, acct04, acct05, acct06, acct07, acct08))) as "Number of Joint Accounts"
  FROM CUSM cm
```

Good solution to tune this script

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements for some sample data (as text, not images); an English (not code) explanation of the logic you are trying to implement; the expected output for that sample data; and if you are having errors with your current code then the full error message (again, as text) or if you are having performance issues then the `EXPLAIN PLAN` for your current code. At the moment it is unclear what you are asking (and if your code works).

Comment: Why do you think that the issue is in `unpivot` itself and why do you expect `cross apply` to be faster? Please provide an actual execution plan that will show wait events, temp disk spills, cerdinalities etc to discuss performance issues.

Comment: Yes i'm not sure 100%, I just knew if take a long time to extract the data ~fetched 50 rows  in 11 seconds. However the full data around 50k rows. It means it will take a long time to extract. I searched in the google and found the some topics show about to convert the unpivote to cross apply. That's why i asked about this.

Comment: Applicate if you can tune this script, I try many times but still not the same

Comment: My code is working fine but i just to tune the script to save the time

Answer (score 0):

Without the `CREATE TABLE` or `INSERT` statements to help debug the performance, it is difficult to make suggestions.

From oracle 12, one possible solution is to use a `LATERAL` join:

```sql
SELECT cm.cust_acct_no as "dd",
       ( SELECT COUNT(1)
         FROM   kyc_count_account kca
         WHERE  (  kca.CUST_ACCT_NO = LPAD(t.link_cua_acno_01, 16, '0')
                OR kca.CUST_ACCT_NO = LPAD(t.link_cua_acno_02, 16, '0')
                OR kca.CUST_ACCT_NO = LPAD(t.link_cua_acno_03, 16, '0')
                OR kca.CUST_ACCT_NO = LPAD(t.link_cua_acno_04, 16, '0')
                OR kca.CUST_ACCT_NO = LPAD(t.link_cua_acno_05, 16, '0')
                OR kca.CUST_ACCT_NO = LPAD(t.link_cua_acno_06, 16, '0')
                OR kca.CUST_ACCT_NO = LPAD(t.link_cua_acno_07, 16, '0')
                OR kca.CUST_ACCT_NO = LPAD(t.link_cua_acno_08, 16, '0')
                )
         AND    kca.active_account = 1
       ) as "Number of Joint Accounts"
FROM   CUSM cm
       LEFT OUTER JOIN LATERAL (
         SELECT *
         FROM   cbsdbap1.cusvcc t
         WHERE  SUBSTR(t.key_1, 4, 16) = cm.cust_acct_no
         AND    t.code = 'CC'
         FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY
       ) t
       ON (1 = 1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the soluction. This script also fine but it still catch up data a long time (50 rows 11seconds). Appreciate if you can support to tune script again.

Comment: --------Result-------------------------


dd     Number of Join Accounts
0000000000010000  3
0000000000010001  5
0000000000010002  5
0000000000010003  4
0000000000010004  5
0000000000010005  6
0000000000010006  2
0000000000010007  3
0000000000010008  9
0000000000010009  4
0000000000010010  5

Comment: @ChhornMengHong And we would appreciate it if **YOU** would [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77321633/edit) and provide a [MRE] with the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements for some sample data that replicates the issues; details of the expected output for that sample data; and the `EXPLAIN PLAN` for your query. We are not going to endlessly rewrite a query when we have no way of testing it and no idea of where the problem is.

Comment: Thanks M10 for your recommendation. I also shared the sample record in the comment already. Appreciate if you can support to tune script again.

Comment: @ChhornMengHong Please see my previous comment (on both the question and this answer).